# Unable to use spectrum for color picker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

I used the cdn script and link to import the spectrum plugin in my HMTL code:

```
<!-- Jquery Color Picker -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/spectrum-colorpicker2/dist/spectrum.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/spectrum-colorpicker2/dist/spectrum.min.css">
```

And after that  I used a input tag :
`<input type="text" maxlength="6" size="6" id="colorSelector" value="00ff00" />`
And a jquery function to call spectrum.

The jquery code is here:

```
$("#colorSelector").spectrum({
          type: "component",
          showPalette: false,
          showInput: true,
          showInitial: true,
          showButtons: false
     });
```

I get this error in the browser:
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).spectrum is not a function

And of course I'm using this jquery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Edit: Added snippet

```js
$(function() {
  $("#colorSelector").spectrum({
    type: "component",
    showPalette: false,
    showInput: true,
    showInitial: true,
    showButtons: false
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/spectrum-colorpicker2/dist/spectrum.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/spectrum-colorpicker2/dist/spectrum.min.css">

<input type="text" maxlength="6" size="6" id="colorSelector" value="00ff00" />
```

Comment: You code works fine for me, so you can check the following. 1) Ensure you have included the spectrum scrip after you include jquery and before you use `.spectrum()`. You can also try wrap your `$("#colorSelector").spectrum` in `$(document).ready(function() {})`

Comment: I've added a snippet - as you can it works fine.   This may be because the snippet runs js code last so doesn't need a doc ready (in the snippet).  I've added the doc.ready anyway so you can see how to change it in your code to see if it makes a difference.